# compiler: should I read entire file for scanning

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

I am in the phase of scanning to build a compiler. I wonder if I should read entire file content before processing? I think it should be better since my compiler may need to do some optimization later (so I dont need to reread the file). But what if the input program is kinda big, it could take lots of memory to hold the file content.

Need some more ideas and discussion.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that 16 megabytes is at the same time a quantity of memory so small that it's not even noticed on nowadays computer and roughly the source code output of a professional programmer working for a year (give or take). Unless you plan to compile generated code, do you realize what it would mean for your compiler's input to exhaust memory? The "if the input program is kinda big" clause in your question is laughable.

Comment: For multipass compilers, 1st pass is on source code. How about 2nd, 3rd, ... passes? Any compiler that work on source code several times?

Comment: Excuse me, but why are you building a compiler?  This is a very basic question, and I'd think anybody with sufficient knowledge to build one would know it already.

Comment: @user203123 Usually, pass (n+1) works on the output of pass n. You really need to work on compilation techniques before you start your compiler. And a last piece of advice if you allow me: don't try to do it with regular expressions.

Comment: I'm the beginner in compiler. I'm working on theory and practice at the same time. This is not a real project so I guess I can work it this way.

Comment: Nothing wrong with playing around with a compiler, but I'd think without some more knowledge it could be frustrating.  BTW, regular expressions may be useful for the very first step, separating characters into tokens, depending on the language.  After that, you will definitely need more powerful tools.

Answer (score 1):

Optimization should not normally require a second pass over the actual source code - the first thing you should do is to tokenise it and then work on the tokenised version. The on;y reason for hanging on to the source is if you need to exactly reproduce it in your error messages, which you probably don't.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the first think you do is a lexical analysis in which you split the input file into tokens. Then you build a symbol table and an abstract syntax tree. Any optimization or code generation then works on these intermediate data structures rather than on the original input file. Hence, I see no point in completely reading and buffering the input file.

Answer (score 1):

Optimizations would happen on the [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) or some later intermediate representation, not on the source code. And the AST will definitely need to fit entirely in memory. The source code doesn't, because it can be transformed into the AST on-the-fly.